# How to remove Windows app package MSIX from .net app?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net, msix

Currently my application is using `PackageManager.AddPackageAsync` to add another package(msix file) of mine to WindowsApps, this function does not return any information related to **Package**.

Then I have another function to remove a pagekage(msix file) from WindowsApps, I found function `PackageManager.RemovePackageAsync` but the input is **packageFullName**. I've researched but haven't found a way to get it from my app yet.
Is there any way to get **packageFullName** from .NET code (C# or VB.NET), or any idea how to remove pagekage from WindowsApps with input as **MSIX file**?

(Sorry for my English)

Comment: You can improve the question using some AI engines ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.Id.FullName
```